# vlookup function doesn't work with cell change handler

Tags: excel

I use Excel. I have two files and '=vlookup' function that imports values from another file.

I have set cell change handler like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, [b1]) Is Nothing Then
        [c1].Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End Sub
```

So I want to see it orange colored if value of 'vlookup' cell changes from another file. But it doesn't work.

P.S. If I use on cell change for manual cell change, it works. But doesn't work with 'vlookup'.

Comment: You need to use the ***Calculate*** event handler rather than the ***Worksheet_Change*** handler.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent could you explain this, please? I tried Calculate instead of Change and nothing happened. I may do smth wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Worksheet_Change()` event occurs when you **manually** change cells' formula or value.
When the other file changes and causes the `vlookup` cell changes, that's not because you change it (you don't have to type anything) but it's recalculated.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
    [c1].Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to do this with all cells in C column? What syntax I should use?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Columns(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub

Comment: Thanks, but it makes whole column another colored. I mean, if there is a way to set c5 if b5 value changes the same way as change c8 if b8 value changes

Comment: @NarekHiulazian There is no such thing. The whole sheet is recalculated, not a specific cell. You might wanna try store the values in a different column and check which cells has changed value.

Comment: I understand hole sheet is recalculated. I see every cell in column changed its color, but I need to change color separately if its appropriate call changed value via vlookup. So, what you will advise to do?

Comment: @NarekHiulazian The thing that every cell in the column changed its color doesn't mean the whole sheet is recalculated. I think you're understanding the wrong way. But nevermind.

Comment: @NarekHiulazian I advised you to store the values in another column and check which cells have changed value. Now I suggest a little bit different. The same idea but using `Conditional Formatting` can be better. Copy the value of column C to (let's say) column D. Set `Conditional Formatting` of column C: if C_i <> D_i then colors orange.

Comment: thanks for your help. But I am new in excel and I really need only this in my file. I have seen Conditional Formatting and I guess I don't know place where to set this rule and how to write it correctly: if C_i <> D_i then colors orange

Comment: Select cell C1, go to Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > Type `=C1 <> D1` to the formula text box > Click Format button and choose the format you want > Copy cell C1 and paste to all column C.

Comment: Thanks. And tell me if I should leave VBA like this? Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() Columns(3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 End Sub

Comment: @NarekHiulazian. No. Remove it.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work for me. Tried multiple times. Thanks you your help